# OpenCV + flask - show different image, when JSON received

Tags: python, json, opencv, flask

I have a simple FLASK web server, which is waiting for the JSON request.
When JSON is received as {"card": "AC"} it will show me the AC.png card image with OpenCV.
That works. But then it should update & show me the JC.png card when any different JSON is received... that's when it freezes. What am I doing wrong?

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask, request
import cv2
app = Flask(__name__)

img = cv2.imread('AC.png',1)
img2 = cv2.imread('JC.png',1)

#make window fullscreen
# cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
# cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print("Data received from Webhook is: ", request.json)
        message = request.json
        #print(message["card"])

        #When JSON with "AC" received, show AC card
        if message["card"] == "AC":
            print('first')
            cv2.imshow("window", img)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

        else:
            print('second')
            cv2.imshow("window", img2) #show JC card
            cv2.waitKey(1)

        return "Webhook received!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want `cv2.waitKey(1)` in there? That may be causing the freeze waiting for a key press.

Comment: cv2.waitKey(0) is waiting for key press, cv2.waitKey(1) is just 1ms, must be there if I want to update the window